# Cordova App using VS

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm developing a `cross-platform` mobile app using `Cordova` in `visual studio`.
The problem is that I need a database to store and retrieve data, usually I create local database inside the visual studio, but I cannot find the localDB option within a `Cordova` app. So, if anyone can help me with creating a database and connect it to the `Cordova` app? What are the best methods/ways to do it?

Comment: use sqlite database of android to store data in database you will get many links related to thid

Answer (score 0):

Please check [here](https://phonegappro.com/tutorials/phonegap-sqlite-tutorial-with-example-apache-cordova/). Hopefully, it will be helpful with you.

Comment: I'm using localDB (.mdf) .. this is not what I'm looking for and this plugin within the tutorial doesn't seem to work with me, but thnkx any way